# Virtual PDF printer on the network

Tags: printing, printer, hp-printer

I have an application that only allows very rudimentary printer settings. In principle, only the IP of a network printer can be specified, which is then addressed via IPP (port 9100).

Now I would like to get rid of the physical printers used for this and provide several virtual PDF printers in the network. At first I thought of a classic CUPS server with PDF printing. The problem, however, is that these printers are addressed via a URL, e.g. http://printserver/printers/PDF. But in the above mentioned program only one IP can be entered and not a URL.

Is it possible under Linux to provide a virtual printer that is addressed exclusively via an IP address?

Comment: If you have working physical printers with this, first thing I'd do is run `wireshark` and see which URL the application is actually using (it will be an URL, even if you just specify the IP address, because IPP is based on HTTP). If CUPS can't be configured to deal with this URL, and small HTTP proxy which translates the URL won't be that difficult to write, if you know how to program. Maybe an existing HTTP proxy that allows rewriting rules is already sufficient.

Comment: However, I'd assume CUPS to understand the usual IPP protocol out of the box, see e.g. [here](https://www.cups.org/doc/spec-ipp.html)

Comment: CUPS is able do do it AFAIR